# How does serialize get access to private attributes

Tags: php, serialization

When I do the following,

```
class TestObject {
  private $testField = "12345";
}

echo json_encode((new TestObject()));
echo serialize((new TestObject()));
```

I get `{}` for json_encode() but `O:10:"TestObject":1:{s:21:"TestObjecttestField";s:5:"12345";}` for serialize().

I will like to better understand how they both work under the hood. How serialize() is able to access private attributes. Also why can't json_encode() do same.

Comment: `private` properties aren't fundamentally "inaccessible". `private` isn't for security and doesn't mean "can't touch this". There are any number of ways of "working around" `private` access restrictions. It's rather about that `serialize` is supposed to produce a storable representation of any value that can be unserialised into the exact same object again; for that purpose it obviously needs to include `private` properties, or it couldn't reproduce the same object.